# SharedPreferences not updated on change, only with app reset?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am developing an app that displays a rule in relation to card being drawn. The user can set custom rules in the `SettingsActivity` and this is loaded into the `GameActivity`.

This works no problem, however, if the user decides to change their rules, or reset to default, the only way for this to update in the `GameActivity` is to fully quit the App and restart. I have tried using `reCreate()`, but it didn't work. and when I used `finish()`, it just quit the app completely.

In the `GameActivity`, I also tried putting my call to the loadRules method in the `onResume()` method, but it did nothing.

Code snipped from SettingsActivity:

```
public void setDefault(View v){

ruleAce = rules[0];
ruleTwo = rules[1];
ruleThree = rules[2];
ruleFour = rules[3];
ruleFive = rules[4];
ruleSix = rules[5];
ruleSeven = rules[6];
ruleEight = rules[7];
ruleNine = rules[8];
ruleTen = rules[9];
ruleJack = rules[10];
ruleQueen = rules[11];
ruleKing = rules[12];

saveRules();

}

private void saveRules(){

SharedPreferences ace, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, jack, queen, king;

SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
ace = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = ace.edit();
editor.putString(RULE_ACE, ruleAce);
editor.apply();

two = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = two.edit();
editor.putString(RULE_TWO, ruleTwo);
editor.apply();

three = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = three.edit();
editor.putString(RULE_THREE, ruleThree);
editor.apply();

four = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = four.edit();
editor.putString(RULE_FOUR, ruleFour);
editor.apply();

five = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = five.edit();
editor.putString(RULE_FIVE, ruleFive);
editor.apply();

six = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = six.edit();
editor.putString(RULE_SIX, ruleSix);
editor.apply();

seven = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = seven.edit();
editor.putString(RULE_SEVEN, ruleSeven);
editor.apply();

eight = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = eight.edit();
editor.putString(RULE_EIGHT, ruleEight);
editor.apply();

nine = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = nine.edit();
editor.putString(RULE_NINE, ruleNine);
editor.apply();

ten = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = ten.edit();
editor.putString(RULE_TEN, ruleTen);
editor.apply();

jack = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = jack.edit();
editor.putString(RULE_JACK, ruleJack);
editor.apply();

queen = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = queen.edit();
editor.putString(RULE_QUEEN, ruleQueen);
editor.apply();

king = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = king.edit();
editor.putString(RULE_KING, ruleKing);
editor.apply();

}
```

GameActivity snippet:

```
public class kingGame extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_king_game);

loadRules();

shuffleDeck();
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
super.onResume();
setContentView(R.layout.activity_king_game);

loadRules();
}

//Sets the Rules
static String aceRule, twoRule, threeRule, fourRule, fiveRule, sixRule, sevenRule, eightRule, nineRule, tenRule, jackRule, queenRule, kingRule;
static String[] defaultrules = {DEFAULT RULES IN HERE}

public void loadRules(){

SharedPreferences settings;
settings = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


aceRule = settings.getString(RULE_ACE, defaultrules[0]);
twoRule = settings.getString(RULE_TWO, defaultrules[1]);
threeRule = settings.getString(RULE_THREE, defaultrules[2]);
fourRule = settings.getString(RULE_FOUR, defaultrules[3]);
fiveRule = settings.getString(RULE_FIVE, defaultrules[4]);
sixRule = settings.getString(RULE_SIX, defaultrules[5]);
sevenRule = settings.getString(RULE_SEVEN, defaultrules[6]);
eightRule = settings.getString(RULE_EIGHT, defaultrules[7]);
nineRule = settings.getString(RULE_NINE, defaultrules[8]);
tenRule = settings.getString(RULE_TEN, defaultrules[9]);
jackRule = settings.getString(RULE_JACK, defaultrules[10]);
queenRule = settings.getString(RULE_QUEEN, defaultrules[11]);
kingRule = settings.getString(RULE_KING, defaultrules[12]);

}
/* Creates the Deck */

/* Shuffles the Deck */
public void shuffleDeck(){

cardsLeft = 52;
cardNum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < RANK.length; i++){
    for (int j=0; j < SUITS.length; j++){
        deck[SUITS.length*i + j] = RANK[i] + " Of " + SUITS[j];
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    int r = i + (int) (Math.random() * (n-i));
    String temp = deck[r];
    deck[r] = deck[i];
    deck[i] = temp;
}
}

/* Button Press Draws the Card */
public void drawCard(View view) {}
```

After that it is just the methods to `printCard()`, `showRule()`, and `newGame()`.

newGame is only called when the game finishes (reaches the end of the deck).

showRule just displays the rules loaded into aceRule, twoRule, etc in response to which card is drawn.

printCard displays the drawn card.

So my question is, how do I force the `GameActivity` to check for changes in the `SharedPreferences` when the activity is resumed?

Answer (score 0):

In the onPause method, you could save the values with .edit().putX().apply() on the shared prefs object